# Boost API doc location?

Tags: boost

I was wondering if there is a javadoc style API reference for the boost libraries?

I have noticed that there are class descriptions with these type of urls:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html

Whereas documentation of particular libraries is at the following:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options/

Notice the html/boost subdirectory. Considering this, perhaps there is an organized/categorized API index for these raw indexes:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/ ?

Comment: That is a link to a directory of Boost libraries linking to documentation of the libraries, not an api doc specifying the class definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost is a collection of many [different libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/), by many different authors. There is no comprehensive documentation. Several of the libraries provide API documentation as you have already noted. I think the [Asio API documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) is particularly well written.